# can anyone explain me the background process of this code

Tags: python-3.x

```
input_string = input("Enter family members separated by space ")
family_list = input_string.split(" ")
print("\n")
print("Here is the list in alphabetical order:")

for name in sorted (family_list):
    print(name)
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What do you mean by the background process?

Comment: Generally, this code should return the sorted order of string in the manner of word by word but as I run this code it returns nothing to me. so I want the reason why is it happening soo!!

Comment: Please clarify what parts you are familiar with, and what level of detail you are looking for. „The background process“ goes arbitrarily deep. See the [ask] page how to pose an answerable, on-topic question and best help us help you. If you feel the code behaves unexpectedly, provide a [mcve] *including input, as well as expected and actual output*.

Comment: Only a function can _return_ anything. You do not define any functions here, so nothing, naturally, gets returned. What was your input?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1. input_string = input("Enter family members separated by space ")**

This line request for a user to enter names, separate them by commas. The names are stored as a single string in "*input_string*"

**2. family_list = input_string.split(" ")**

This line will convert the names in the string into arrays by separating them by the use a comma.

**3. print("\n")**

This line prints an empty line.

**4. print("Here is the list in alphabetical order:")**
This line will just print the text in quotes inside the print function in a new line

**5. for name in sorted (family_list): print(name)**

This line will take the array names created at line 2, sort them alphabetically then print then line by line following that order.

Comment: @alert Alberto, I too expected this but as I run this code it returns nothing to me. so I want the reason why is it happening soo!!

Comment: Take note that the primary sequence type in Python is a list, not an array. The name array is commonly used for specific types that hold native machine types (array.array and numpy.array).

Comment: What editor/IDE are you using and what version of python are you using?